# закрытие блока по клику на кнопку и вне блока

Tags: javascript, html

Есть выпадающее меню которое открывается по клику на бургер, не могу сделать закрытие меню и по клику снова на бургер и закрытие по клику вне области
если добавляю код закрытия по клику вне блока то закрытие меню по клику на кнопку не работает

```
$('.header__hamburger').on('click', function(){
        $('.header__menu-mobile').toggleClass('mobile-menu-active');
});
```

Вот код закрытия меню по клику вне области

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $(".header__menu-mobile");
        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
            $('.header__menu-mobile').removeClass('mobile-menu-active');
        }
    });
```

Совместить эти функции не получается что бы закрывало и по клику на кнопку и по клику вне области

Вот разметка

```
        <div class="header__hamburger">
            <div class="hamburger hamburger--emphatic">
                <div class="hamburger-box">
                    <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="header__menu-mobile">

            <div class="menu-mobile__second">
                <a href="#">Подарунковий набір</a>
                <a href="#">Подарунковий сертифікат</a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-mobile__middle bb-1">
                <a href="#">Доставка і повернення</a>
                <a href="#">Політика конфіденційності</a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-mobile__footer">
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: неплохо бы кусочек разметки, а то потенциальным отвечающим надо её выдумать

Comment: Спасибо, добавил

Answer (score 0):

Ты удалил класс, а надо задать другой, вроде бы

> С помощью события mouseup вы можете щелкнуть в другом месте на экране, удерживать нажатой кнопку мыши и переместить указатель на элемент mouseup, а затем отпустить указатель мыши.
>
> Событие с кликом требует, чтобы в этом элементе выполнялось событие mousedown и mouseup.
>
> Обычное ожидание состоит в том, что для клика требуется как событие mousedown, так и mouseup, поэтому я рекомендую событие click.
>
> Из возможного дубликата видно, что события mouseup и mousedown также могут быть вызваны кнопками мыши, кроме кнопки левого щелчка. Это очень отличается от того, что ожидал общий пользователь.

Comment: Ну у меня же меню открытое когда класс добавлен, то логично что, что бы закрыть его класс надо удалить, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: я когда делал, у меня есть класс закрытого блока, я меняю клас на открытый блок и обратно

Comment: Дело в том, что в принципе клик не работает когда меню открыто, ничего не происходит

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/task/sliding-menu

Comment: Может это поможет

Comment: У меня это сделано, мне надо к этому добавить что бы еще по клику вне блока оно сворачивалось и остался ивент на закрытие по клику на кнопку

Comment: можно же повесть событие закрытия на остальную область, если меню открыто то закрыть

Comment: я повесил, выше код, но клик на закрытие по кнопке не работает. после того как добавил код закрытия вне области

Comment: С помощью события mouseup вы можете щелкнуть в другом месте на экране, удерживать нажатой кнопку мыши и переместить указатель на элемент mouseup, а затем отпустить указатель мыши.
Событие с кликом требует, чтобы в этом элементе выполнялось событие mousedown и mouseup.
Обычное ожидание состоит в том, что для клика требуется как событие mousedown, так и mouseup, поэтому я рекомендую событие click
Из возможного дубликата видно, что события mouseup и mousedown также могут быть вызваны кнопками мыши, кроме кнопки левого щелчка. Это очень отличается от того, что ожидал общий пользователь

Comment: получается так что ты не правильную для это функцию клика использовал

Comment: то есть mouseup мне надо заменить на click?